# Why is there a difference between select count(*) and select * query planning in SQLite?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm testing some query performance in SQLite, so reviewing query plans, etc.  I ran across this (to me) funny scenario where `select count(*)` lists an index as a covering index while the same query criteria using `select *` uses the same index but does not list it as a covering index.

The queries and results in question:

```
sqlite> explain query plan select count(*) from Table1 cross join Table2 on Table1.Id = Table2.Id and Table1.ExportTime >= Table2.InsertTime;
0|0|0|SCAN TABLE Table1 (~5000 rows)
0|1|1|SEARCH TABLE Table2 USING COVERING INDEX test_2 (Id=? AND InsertTime<?) (~167 rows)

sqlite> explain query plan select * from Table1 cross join Table2 on Table1.Id = Table2.Id and Table1.ExportTime >= Table2.InsertTime;
0|0|0|SCAN TABLE Table1 (~5000 rows)
0|1|1|SEARCH TABLE Table2 USING INDEX test_2 (Id=? AND InsertTime<?) (~167 rows)
```

Why is this the case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A covering index is an index that can be used to resolve the entire query such that it is not necessary to read the table.  With the `select *` query, it would be necessary to read the table to retrieve the column values.  With the `select count(*)`, it can find the result (the count) solely by using the indexes.

Comment: Thanks, the covering index explanation was the piece of info I was missing.  I just came to the same realisation myself after tweaking the `select` version to only return Id, which resulted in it reporting the index as a covering index.  https://www.sqlite.org/queryplanner.html then explained the concept to me.